# Getting detailed crash dumps from a hooked exe

Tags: visual-c++, hook, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I am trying find a problem with my program that is hooking into a game. This is
vc++. Basically I launch the program and then hook into it using SDL. When I run the code from VS2010, all works fine. But when I try to run from command prompt, my program can launch the game, but after that the game crashes immediately.

I was viewing windows event logs, and it appears that there is an access violation. 0xc000005

How can I log any further details about the program that crashes? I tried "procdump" but that is not useful as I cannot INDIRECTLY target the hooked game from console. Rather it can only target my application that hooks.

Anyway of getting detailed dumps is highly appreciated in this case. 
Thanks!

Comment: If you don't get the WER crash dialog, the one that gives you lots of time to attach a debugger, then attach it when [the program starts up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513654/how-to-set-breakpoint-at-the-very-beginning-of-program-execution).

Comment: Run VS2010 IDE with `/debugexe` option. I.e. `> vcvarsall.bat` then `> devenv.exe /debugexe YourProgram.exe`. If you want to generate minidump on error, you may use domething like this: https://github.com/myaut/tsload/blob/master/agent/test/common/fault.c

Comment: Ok thanks, I am going to give it a try.

Comment: I will try both methods!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform postmortem debugging by using a combination of the [WER registry keys/values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to trap any dump that is produced. I’ve used this method to prevent the WER system from collecting the dump file (.dmp).  I’ve also written about this in another [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848126/make-crashdumps-dump-into-same-folder-that-app-runs-from/27862359#27862359).  To accomplish this, you will need to create a registry key under

> Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting

if one does not already exist.  The key should be

> LocalDumps\*your application*.exe

Once that’s done, modify these keys/values to meet your needs:

> DumpCount, DumpFolder, DumpType

You’ll need Administrator rights to create and modify the keys, and, you should reset everything you’ve modified when you’re done debugging.