# Get Excel mini dump file without WER (Windows error reporting)

Tags: c++, excel, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

I develop an unmanaged C++ XLL addin for Excel targeted for Windows 7 and would like to be able to get the dmp file locally when there is a crash.  I understand it can be sent to Microsoft and I can subscribe to WER to get it that way but there is a ton of overhead with that.  I just need the core dump.  Is it possible with an Office product.  I've read that setting some registry value was possible before but I don't know if its possible on Windows 7 with an office product.

Ps: I tried setting SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() and redirect to my own handler where i would call MiniDumpWriteDump my self but Excel must set the filter before as mine never gets hit.

Edit:
While not a complete success yet I discovered that if I set the registry setting DontShowUI in the Windows Error Reporting key then the crash dump is generated into %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue.  I cant redirect it yest and its for all application but its something to start

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30469083/4136325

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a WER account to trap the minidump file.  You should be able to get the dump file from Excel if it follows the same crash reporting methodology (and, it should).  Your suspicions are correct.  You'll need to set some [WER regsitry keys and values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I've written about this in other posts.  Please refer to [Getting detailed crash dumps from a hooked exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234165/getting-detailed-crash-dumps-from-a-hooked-exe/28237143#28237143) for more information.

Comment: rrirwer, thank you for the reply,  I saw your previous answer and have tried this but no dump is caught.  Do you know if this works with excel 2007 specifically?

Comment: I wouldn't expect Excel to use a different methodology to produce a crash report.  If you follow the outlined steps from those posts, it should work correctly.

Comment: I tried everything and this does not seem to work.  If I want dumps from EXECEL.EXE and I want them to go to C:\DUMPDATA what are the registry  entries I need to set?

Comment: As I indicated, Excel may use a different crash reporting methodology. But, if it doesn't, you'll need to set LocalDumps\Excel.exe, DumpCount, DumpType, and DumpFolder.  Make sure you have admin rights when defining the registry keys/values.

Comment: I did that and I have admin rights on my machine.. I believe office products do something different.  At least I cant get the above to work,