# How to capture crash dump for unhandled exception using procdump

Tags: windows, crash-dumps

Below is a code snippet where I deliberately cause 2 NullPointerException. The first one is handled. Whereas the second one goes unhandled. I want to create a crash dump on the second exception when a crash would occur.

```
int* nullPtr = NULL;
try{
    x = *nullPtr;
} 
catch(...) {
    QLOG_WARNING0(QTEXT("catching 1st null ptr exception."));
}
y = *nullPtr;
```

This does crash the process but the dump is not generated using -e option only.
What options should I use to get the dump?

Or is there a way I could achieve this with debugDiag tool? If so, how?

This is only a sample code. The actual use case I am debugging has a process crashing but I am unable to take dumps for the crash. There are valid handled exceptions where the dump is getting triggerred in case I use the first chance option( - e 1). This is causing procdump to exit before the actual crash occurs.

Comment: Are you required to use Procdump?  There are other ways to collect a crash dump.

Comment: No I am open to any other tool. I did find out "debugDiag" for instance, but unable to solve my purpose  with this either(given my level of expertise). There could be a way out with these or maybe some other tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> “No I am open to any other tool.”

Per your comment, there are other ways to trap a dump file.  In my answer to [Getting detailed crash dumps from a hooked exe,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234165/getting-detailed-crash-dumps-from-a-hooked-exe/28237143#28237143)
 you’ll see that you can set some registry key settings to trap the dump from an unhandled exception.  The settings assume you have Windows Error Reporting **enabled**.  I’ve gone so far as to incorporate those settings into a small utility program that my company uses when debugging difficult customer crashes.

Comment: Thank you. This did help me.