# Windows Error Reporting doesn't generate mini dump for a .NET 4 application sometimes

Tags: .net, clr, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

I'm trying to [diagnose a crash issue for a .NET 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601581/nullreferenceexception-from-an-impossible-place#comment49348656_30601581). The last time it crashes in a user's machine, Windows Error Reporting doesn't gather the mini dump of the application. I've check the `DumpFolder` in registry, and I can find the dump files for old crashes, but there's just no new dump file for the last one.

The event log of the crash says:

> Application: MyApp.exe 
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319 
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error int the .NET Runtime at IP 000007FEEC0F25E8 (000007FEEC0B0000) with exit code 80131506.

By some searching is looks like a famous bug of concurrent GC in CLR x64. The event log is also different from previous crashes. In previous event logs, they said explicitly there's an "access violation" happen. The exit code is the same.

I cannot using `adplus` or `procdump` to get crash dump since they slow down the performance significantly. I want to know why this time WER didn't get a mini dump?

Comment: How exactly did you tell WER to create a dump? What are your Registry settings?

Comment: Some potential causes: incorrect Registry settings, disk full, wrong permissions on the folder, unhandled exception handler in the application, AeDebug setting in addition to WER

Comment: The same happens to me. Some applications when crash do not generate a dump (like word).

Answer (score 4):

The dump file may have been processed and sent onto the WER collection system on the Microsoft servers.  You should be able to verify that by checking the path…

> C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive

Having said that, there’s nothing stopping you from trapping the dump.  You’ll need to set some [registry values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx) to accomplish that.  I’ve posted the procedure in a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848126/make-crashdumps-dump-into-same-folder-that-app-runs-from/27862359#27862359) to a similar problem.

Comment: The user doesn't see the WER dialog and there's no crash dump for this time under `DumpFolder` but we can find old dumps there. If we use `Environment.FailFast` to crash the application in the same machine we can also get crash dump. I believe the system default settings work fine - expect last time.

Comment: @Jeffrey Zhao WER does not discriminate when collecting dumps.  It doesn't pick and choose what dumps to collect.  If you want to collect the dump, I've given you a way to trap it locally before it is sent on.  Is your priority to solve the crash, or, figure out why "Windows Error Reporting doesn't generate mini dump"?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why "Windows Error Reporting doesn't generate mini dump" at that time, but it generates mini dump successfully before and after. The settings you mentioned are already been set and is the system default.